# JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected result may occur. Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I am trying to install jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.
First I remarqued that I can't access the administration page of JBoss. Then I tried to add user and password from the command prompt and I saw this message appear:

> JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected result may occur. Set JAVA_HOME to the    directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.

When I've search for the problem, I've understand that I have to set java_home in the run.bat. But my run.bat content is different:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Placeholder for people used to run.sh from older version redirecting them to read the readme
echo 
echo ========================================================================================
echo 
echo To start JBoss Application Server please see `pwd`/../README.txt
echo 
echo ========================================================================================
echo
```

Comment: which OS you are using ?

Comment: Windows 8 @AmitBhati

Comment: You are confusing `run.bat` for Windows with a `run.sh` meant for Linux.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: when I open run it opens like a cmd and closes immediately

Answer (score 8):

`JAVA_HOME` is generally set as a Environmental(classpath) variable in your OS.
Batch files generally pick up `JAVA_HOME` value dynamically from this variable.

In Windows OS :-

Right click on `My Computer` > `Advanced system settings` > `Environment Variables` > `Environment Variables` > `New` > Variable Name as `JAVA_HOME` > Variable Value as JDK installation home path.

As @laune mentioned, you need to run `run.bat` not `run.sh`

For creating user, refer this https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/add-user+utility

Comment: Classpath variable? Environment variable, you mean.

Comment: Yeah, right. You can set the JAVA_HOME in environmental variables.

Comment: That solved the problem of the msg but still cant access to adinastration page of jBoss,; when i put localhost:8080 i always have that :

Comment: i have the enter the username and password ; i've create them and when i enter them i got the same window to enter the username and password

Comment: I've remarque when i start Jboss server on eclipse these just 3 first line whitch appear

Comment: Refer the post, I added in my answer. Create the user by using add-user.bat. Create the user in management-realm which is default to be able to access the web console.

Comment: Yes @AmitBhati  I've add a new user but when i use them to log in , they re ask me for username and password again

Comment: @KaoutarLaz That's a separate question, so you need to post a separate question for it. But be sure to first search carefully to see that it hasn't been answered before.

Comment: @KaoutarLaz, put the screenshots of the steps you are performing while creating a user and when trying to access the web console.

Comment: I'm tring to add images but i reknow how to dd image in stackoverflow @AmitBhati

Comment: Click on edit your question, then at the top of your edit window, there is an image option,  just click on it and select the image from your machine which need to be uploaded.

Comment: they sad i need 10 reputations to put image ??!! can u contact me on other thing like facebook @Amit Bhati

Comment: Ok Amit460021@gmail.com...search my profile and ping me on facebook.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on Ubuntu, then the solution is:

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

after that, you can continue your installation.